# PHP : Error `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Tags: php

I new in PHP , I want to make an Uploader for image. Here my whole code :

```
<?php
include "checkConnection.php";
$fileName = $_FILES['picture']['name']; //get the file name
$fileSize = $_FILES['picture']['size']; //get the size
$fileError = $_FILES['picture']['error']; //get the error when upload
if($fileSize > 0 || $fileError == 0){ //check if the file is corrupt or error
$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], 'home/mario/public_html/API/Content/Images/'.$fileName); //save image to the folder
........
........
?>
```

I get the error on `$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], 'home/mario/public_html/API/Content/Images/'.$fileName); //save image to the folder`

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(home/mario/public_html/API/Content/Images/1492599446257.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mario/public_html/API/uploadFile.php on line 7

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpPvn44L' to 'home/mario/public_html/API/Content/Images/1492599446257.jpg' in /home/mario/public_html/API/uploadFile.php on line 7
```

I read some article regarding this but its not working. Any suffestion will help for me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its so embarrassed, i forgot the `/` in front on of 'home/....' Its solved.